# Saving data in Java

Tags: java, nested-class, serializable

When you save objects in Java using `java.io.Serializable`, if the object you're saving has objects of different classes within it, do those nested classes also have to implement serializable?

Comment: Yes if you want them to be serialized

Comment: use the "transient" keyword to skip member objects of your class from being serialized. they will need to be initialized again after retreival.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, yes. If your class has non-transient member fields of reference types, and those fields are non-null at runtime, then the objects that those fields refer to must be Serializable in order for the referring object to be Serializable.

There are exceptions to this rule, generally by overriding the default serialization e.g. by implementing private methods that do the serialization by hand. See the comments in the header of the Serializable.java file:

```
 * Classes that require special handling during the serialization and
 * deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact
 * signatures: <p>
 *
 * <PRE>
 * private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
 *     throws IOException
 * private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
 *     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
 * private void readObjectNoData()
 *     throws ObjectStreamException;
 * </PRE>
```

Comment: Can I still just call write on the top-level object? Or would I have to do some recursive stuff

Comment: Yes, you just write the top-level object. Java serialization performs transitive closure on the graph for you.